# Need a report on user and profile

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, report-builder

I want a report on profile 
for every profile the count of users,profile name,User name and frequency of login.
I have created a summary report with group by profile and username.
But how to get count of number of users in profile.
Please suggest.

Comment: You can't get the count of number of users in each profile if you do group by both profile and username. If you remove the group by username, it only have group by profile and thus it returns the count of number of users in that profile.

Comment: but in my report i have added LoginDate column as well,So profile count is showing the total records

Comment: I would have thought this was easiest by creating the report then exporting to Excel or another spreadsheet package which will have a lot more options for summarising the data.

Comment: see the [Power Of One](http://www.adminhero.com/power-of-one-the-most-brilliant-analytics-trick-of-all-time/)

Answer (score 0):

You could have created a report Summarizing Profiles and another groupby Username, this way you could have got the total number of users under a Profile Name and total number of logins by user as you have groupedby Username as well.

I am not sure whether login details would be perfect counts, Instead you can use last login time of every user which will give only one result so you would not require Username Groupby.